# using urlopen to access a page with a javascript packer

Tags: python, urllib2

i'm using urllib2 to open an url and print the html page, but when the page start loading there is a javascript first, and have this:

```
<body onload="challenge();">
```

that load a script and then load the real page, but when i print in this way:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(site)
html = response.read()
print "Get all data: ", html
```

this is the log:

```
Get all data:  <html>
<body onload="challenge();">
<script>
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('1 6(){2.3=\'4=5; 0-7=8; 9=/\';a.b.c()}',13,13,'max|function|document|cookie|website|455b33285501836b3483c1554b8d8c51586bd800|challenge|age|1600|path|window|location|reload'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the html print only the javascript and not the final page, there is a way to print the complete page?

Comment: Are you willing to use a real-client emulation (such as Selenium, etc)?

Comment: it's the only solution?

Comment: Well, you can always parse and "execute" the Javascript string in your Python program...

Comment: can you give me both solution please?

Comment: curl is not a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you unpack the javascript (i.e. execute the eval), you get:

```
function challenge()
{
    document.cookie='website=455b33285501836b3483c1554b8d8c51586bd800; max-age=1600; path=/';
    window.location.reload()
}
```

So you'll need send that cookie when making the HTTP request in order to get the actual page. Something like:

```
import re
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
page = opener.open("<the target URL>").read()
code = re.search('website\|([^|]+)\|',page).group(1)

opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'website='+code+'; max-age=1600; path=/'))
r = opener.open("<the target URL>")
print r.read()
```

which 1) gets the initial page, 2) extracts the cookie code, 3) requests the page again with the correct cookie.